# rails can't count association on validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

Let's say I have a model like that:

```
class Taskable < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :deliveries
  has_many :packages
  has_many :supplies

  validate :can_have_only_one_type_of_association

private

  def can_have_only_one_type_of_association
    unless [deliveries, packages, supplies].count(:any?) <= 1
      errors.add(:base, :can_have_only_one_type_of_association) # becomes invalid if at least two associations present
    end
  end
end
```

The model has validation method `can_have_only_one_type_of_association`. But, if I create an elements to the few associations, I still has valid record.

```
taskable = Taskable.create(taskable_params)
taskable.supplies << Supply.create(supply_params)
taskable.deliveries << Delivery.create(delivery_params)
taskable.reload
taskable.supplies.count # => 1
taskable.deliveries.count # => 1
taskable.valid? # => true (should be false)
```

It seems like activerecord cache these methods somewhere. How can I avoid this unpredictable behaviour?

Comment: If you run the script in console can you see Rails attempts to query the database for checking the `any?` of your relations?

Comment: No, it doesn't send anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like something's wrong with this query:

```
unless [deliveries, packages, supplies].count(:any?) <= 1
```

Maybe it should have &?

```
unless [deliveries, packages, supplies].count(&:any?) <= 1
```

Works in my console.